# How to suppress windows command output?

Tags: windows, console, command, suppress

I'm moving thousands of files through the command line and it prints all the file names to the  console. Is there a way to ignore the output so it can go faster? Something like piping to /dev/null in Linux.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, Windows has an equivalent of "/dev/null": `nul:`

Comment: I'd recommend you instead pipe the output to a file (in a different folder) just in case something unexpected happens and you need to check it.  This will be slightly slower than piping to nul but the difference is unlikely to be perceptible.

Comment: Use This : `move * >nul 2>nul`

Answer (score 7):

```
bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla 2> nul
```

Comment: This does not suppress warnings though.

Comment: @ZinanXing Check current variant

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and I solved like this:

```
move aaa bbb >nul 2>nul
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this will do the trick:

```
MOVE oldfile.wp newfile.doc >nul
```

Source: http://ss64.com/nt/move.html