# Suppress Windows command output when using 'ExecWait' in NSIS

Tags: nsis

I am trying to suppress the output window which pops up after executing a psql command in NSIS

```
ExecWait 'psql -U postgres -f "Path\To\File.sql" postgres'
```

I tried    '>nul' after looking at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463544/how-to-suppress-windows-command-output). But that doesn't work.

Comment: 'psql -q' hides the output but doesn't suppress the errors.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To avoid the black DOS box, you can use [nsExec::Exec](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsExec/nsExec.txt) instead of Execwait.

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla NSIS, you can also use [`ExecShellWait`](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter4.html#basicinstructions) with SW_HIDE like so:

```
ExecShellWait "" "$INSTDIR\myservice.exe" "install" SW_HIDE
```

...although nsExec is clearly the way to go if you want to capture output.